# Yii2: Use one field to search for multiple columns

Tags: php, yii2

I have a table called `calls` and I need a single search input, to search in two columns, `contact_number` and `contact_name`.
How do I do this on Yii2?

**`_search.php`**

```
$form->field($model, 'searchstring')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Search']);
```

**`common\models\CallsSearch.php`**

```
[['searchstring'], 'safe']

(..)

$query->orFilterWhere(['like', 'searchstring', $this->contact_name])
   ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'searchstring', $this->contact_number]);
```

**`controllers\CallsController.php`**

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new CallsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: You should show some code you were trying to do. If you don't know where to start, please check out documentation first and then ask concrete question. No one will write code for you :)

Comment: added an answer see if that helps. moreover, you should add complete `search()`  method from your model for better and accurate code suggestions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you are trying to use the `search_string` input to filter 2 fields `contact_name` or `contact_number` but you are not using it to compare with the fields, you are specifying the custom model attribute as `table_column`, which is wrong, you should change the search model code to the following

```
 $query->andFilterWhere ( [ 'OR' ,
            [ 'like' , 'contact_name' , $this->search_string ],
            [ 'like' , 'contact_number' , $this->search_string ],
        ] );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: happy to help @TiagoV